# CS50 Finance writing to database issue

Tags: python, html, cs50

I am having another issue with CS50 finance and would really appreciate some help.

So I am working on the BUY section, and I have implemented an extra step, where you type in what stock you want, and how much of it you want, then it takes you to a new html page to confirm that you want to buy the stock. This pages tells you how many shares you will buy, how much it costs, and what your cash balance will be after you buy the shares.

My issue is that when I go to actually buy the stock on the confirmation page, I get errors that say my variables (specifically balance, shares and price_per_share) are undefined and I cannot figure out why. I will attached the relevant portions of my code below. Thanks again.

Application.PY:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():

    if request.method == "POST":
        quote = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))

        if quote == None:
            return apology("invalid symbol", 400)

        try:
            shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
        except:
            return apology("shares must be a positive integer", 400)


        if shares <= 0:
            return apology("can't buy less than or 0 shares", 400)

        users= db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id= :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])

        cash_remaining = users[0]["cash"]
        price_per_share = quote["price"]
        total_price = price_per_share * shares
        balance = cash_remaining-total_price
        symbol=quote["symbol"]


        return render_template ("confirmation.html", cash_remaining=cash_remaining, price_per_share=price_per_share, total_price=total_price,shares=shares, symbol=symbol, balance=balance)

    else:
        return render_template ("buy.html")

@app.route("/confirmation", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def confirmation():

    if request.method == "POST":


        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash = :balance WHERE id = :user_id", balance=balance, user_id=session["user_id"])
        db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price_per_share) VALUES(:user_id, :symbol, :shares, :price_per_share)",
                   user_id=session["user_id"],
                   symbol=request.form.get("symbol"),
                   shares=shares,
                   price_per_share=price_per_share)

        flash ("Bought!")

        return render_template("index.html")
    else:
        return render_template("confirmation.html")
```

here is my buy.html code in case needed:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quote
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
     <form action="/buy" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="symbol" placeholder="Symbol" type="text" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="shares" placeholder="Shares Wanted" type="number" min="1" required />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Get Price</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and finally my confirmation.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quote
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/confirmation" method="post">
        <p>Stock Symbol ={{symbol}}</p>
        <p>Shares to be purchased = {{shares}}</p>
        <p>Total Transaction Cost {{total_price | usd}}</p>
        <p>Current Cash = {{cash_remaining | usd}}</p>
        <p>Balance after transaction = {{balance |usd}}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Buy</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So my first check would be what is inside `session`. Just print it's contents and see what's there. If it doesn't look like a dict, print `session.__dict__` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no values submitted with the form in `confirmation.html`. Some options:

- add the data to the session array
- create [`hidden` input controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) to carry the data back to the server
- give the button element a name, and a json encoded string of the values that confirmation will need as its value.

The confirmation route doesn't (try to) get any values from the form (eg `request.form.get`).